# Prove that if all set homeomorphic to X is closed, then X is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X⊂\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that if all set (subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$) homeomorphic to $X$ is closed, then $X$ is compact.

I need some help to think on this problem. There is a similar question, but the first implication is "...homeomorphic to $X$ is bounded...". For this variation of my question, the solution uses a function like
$$f(x) = \frac{x-x_0}{|x-x_0|^2}$$

I have a felling that I need a funtion and try to build some contradiction...but I don't know how. Is this function above useful for my problem?

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Aren't all subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ that are homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ closed?

Comment: @JohnDouma, consider the classic $\{1/n:n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$...

Comment: Let $\Bbb B^n:=\{x\in \Bbb R^n:|x|<1\}$ and consider the homeomorphism $f\colon \Bbb B^n\to \Bbb R^n$ defined by $f(x):=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$. Now, let $Y:=f^{-1}(X)$. From the assumption $X$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$, hence $Y$ is closed in $\Bbb B^n$. Note that non-compact closed subset of $\Bbb B^n$ has a limit point in $\partial \Bbb B^n$. In other words, if $X$ were non-compact, then $Y$ would also so, and then $Y(\subseteq \Bbb B^n\subseteq \Bbb R^n)$ wouldn't be a closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @SumantaDas: you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rob Arthan suggested, I am writing my comments as an answer to remove the question from the unanswered queue. Steps are below:

$(1)$ Let $\Bbb B^n:=\{x\in \Bbb R^n:|x|<1\}$. Consider the map $f\colon \Bbb B^n\to \Bbb R^n$ defined by $f(x):=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$. Note that $f$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}\colon \Bbb R^n\ni z\longmapsto \frac{z}{1+|z|}\in \Bbb B^n$.

$(2)$ Now, let $Y:=f^{-1}(X)$. From the assumption, $X$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$. Since $f^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, $Y$ is closed in $\Bbb B^n$.

$(3)$ Let $A$ be a non-compact closed subset of $\Bbb B^n$. Actually, $\overline A\subseteq \{x\in \Bbb R^n:|x|\leq1\}$. Here, the closure $\overline A$ is taken in $\Bbb R^n$. So, $\overline A$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$ as it is closed in $\Bbb R^n$ as well as a bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Note that $\overline A\cap \Bbb B^n =A$ as $A$ is closed in $\Bbb B^n$. Also, note that $\overline A\backslash \Bbb B^n\neq \varnothing$, otherwise $A$ would be compact subset $\Bbb B^n$. Therefore, there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to some point $\overline A\cap \partial \Bbb B^n$.

$(4)$ Now, if $X$ were non-compact, then $Y(\cong X)$ would be a non-compact closed subset of $\Bbb B^n$, and then $Y$ would have a limit point in $\partial \Bbb B^n$ by $(3)$, i.e.,   $Y$ wouldn't be a closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$, a contradiction to the hypothesis that every homeomorphic copy(in $\Bbb R^n$) of $X$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late, but I was wondering if my solution is right ...

The identity allow us to conclude that $X$ is closed.

To prove that $X$ is bounded, I recall $\mathbb{R}^n\approx B_1(0)$, here the homeomorphism is given by $x\to\frac{x}{1+|x|}$. The restriction of the homeomorphism to $X$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $h(X)\subseteq B_1(0)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, thus $h(X)$ is closed.

If there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ s.t. $|x_n|\geq n$, thus $\{h(x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq h(X)\subseteq B_1(0)$ can be assumed to be a convergent sequence into a value of $h(X)$, by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and closedness of $h(X)$, thus by the continuity of $h^{-1}$ we have that $x_n$ is a convergent sequence into an element of $X$(contradiction).